# How to get the whole array of name in one array object using json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

In my code,i am parsing a JSON object like
`[{"name":"karthi"},{"name":"shreshtt"},{"name":"jitu"},{"name":null},{"name":null},{"name":null},{"name":null}]`

In this, I want to collect all names in an single array object. This is how my controller looks as of now. I want to store the resultant name array in `@hotels` variable.

controller.erb

```
respond_to :json, :xml
  def index
    @hotels = Hotel.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotels.to_json(:only => [ :name ]) }
    end
  end
```

view/hoels/index.json.erb

```
[ 
hotel: <% @hotels.each do |hotel| %>
    { 'name': "<%= hotel.name.to_json.html_safe %>" }
     <% unless index== @hotels.count - 1%>
  <% end %>
   <% end %>
]
```

Comment: What does your `Hotel.all` return? It might be useful if you can provide the schema for the `Hotel` model.

Comment: Could you give the expected output? how it looks like?

Comment: @Priti { "hotels": [ {name:karthick},{"name":"shreshtt"}, ]} i need like this parsing,how to do in my code

Comment: from where `"hotels"` is coming? is it in another array? give me the two arrays ,how does it looks like? expected output I understood.

Comment: @Priti have u understood my expected output,how to do that one,how to do that one,could you edit my code and tell

Answer (score 0):

You want to add just the names to an array?
How about:

```
a = [{name: "karthi"},{name: "shreshtt"},{name: "jitu"},{name: nil},{name: nil},{name: nil},{name: nil}]
@hotel = []
a.collect{|a_name| @hotel << a_name[:name]}
=> ["karthi", "shreshtt", "jitu", nil, nil, nil, nil]
@hotel.compact!
=> ["karthi", "shreshtt", "jitu"]
```

Comment: No dude you are not getting my point, this is the parsing of name now [
  {
    "name": "karthi"
  },
  {
    "name": "shreshtt"
  },] what i want is{ "hotel": [
  {
    "name": "karthi"
  },
  {
    "name": "shreshtt"
  },]} like this i want

Comment: a = [{name: "karthi"},{name: "shreshtt"},{name: "jitu"},{name: nil},{name: nil},{name: nil},{name: nil}], hotels = Hash.new, hotels = {:hotel => a}

Comment: And the output of hotels will be: {:hotel=>[{:name=>"karthi"}, {:name=>"shreshtt"}, {:name=>"jitu"}, {:name=>nil}, {:name=>nil}, {:name=>nil}, {:name=>nil}]}

Comment: what are the changes i have to do in my code,using my code edit and tell

Comment: <% Hotels = {:hotel => @hotels.collect{|h| h.name}} %> hate doing this in views but do it there for now and see if its what you want. Remove what you have in you view and just do this there

Comment: where in which part,i have to do in these line

Comment: in those lines where i have to add <% @hotels.each do |hotel| %>
    { 'name': "<%= hotel.name.to_json.html_safe %>" }

Comment: Do this instead: <% hotels = {:hotel => @hotels.as_json(only: :name)} %>. in your view. This should give you what you want

Comment: dude nothing changes happen,i think you are correct,we have to do something in controller only

Comment: @hotel_names = {:hotel => @hotels.as_json(only: :name)} this in your controller should work. Then you can remove the related code from your view and \@hotel_names will have all the info you need and be avail in your view :)

Comment: Dude if i use ur line instead of my line (format.json { render json: @hotels.to_json(:only =>  :name) } ) in controller. nothing will display

Answer (score 0):

What´s about that?

```
a = {}
a["hotel"] = []
array = [{"name"=>"kathi"}, {"name"=>"kathi2"}, {"name"=>"kathi3"}, {"name"=>"kathi4"}, {"name" => nil}]
a["hotel"] = array
a["hotel"].each do |v|
  if v["name"] == nil
    a["hotel"].delete(v)
  end
end
a => {"hotel"=>[{:name=>"kathi"}, {:name=>"kathi2"}, {:name=>"kathi3"}, {:name=>"kathi4"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following

```
hotels = Hotel.select("name").where("name is not NULL")
json_obj = {hotels: hotels}.to_json

format.json { render json: json_obj }
```

Comment: i have to write this code in controller is it correct?,any other changes i have to do in json.erb?dude

Comment: i dont think you will have to write json.erb any more

Comment: then this code is enough,i have to write alone this code in controller,is it ok